declaring a variable with a specified type in c++
Initially, this seems like very trivial problem.
I have input: string a, string b.
b only takes two values, "string" and "int".
I want to declare a new variable var0 with a type that corresponds to b.
How to implement the logic?
I thought this function would work, but it won't.
auto varx(std::string a, std::string b){  
    if(b == "int") return std::stoi(a);  
    return a;  
}

e.g. auto var0 = varx("43", "int"); should set var0 as int var0 = 43;
I have seen union or variant in discussions, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

C++ doesn't support this. A function needs to have a specific return type that can be inferred at compile time. The concept of a function that "sometimes returns an int" and "sometimes returns a string" doesn't exist like it does in Python and Javascript.

Basically, auto has to be inferred at compile time as well.

This really seems like a you need to take a step back and reexamine what you're doing. What are you actually trying to accomplish here? What's the use case?

What do you want to do? Why do you think you need this? In general you cannot specialize on return type in C++, no matter what.  I think you're looking for serialization. If that is so try to use a 3rd party library (e.g. protobuf/flatbuffer or something like nlohman/json)

You can do that using the desired functionality in C++, you can use std::variant to handle the different types dynamically.
Here is a snippet:
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

// Define a variant that can hold either an int or a string
using VariantType = std::variant<int, std::string>;

VariantType varx(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
    if (b == "int") {
        return std::stoi(a);  // Convert the string to an int
    }
    return a;  // Return the string as is
}

int main() {
    VariantType var0 = varx("43", "int");
    VariantType var1 = varx("Hello", "string");

    // To get the value out of the variant, you need to use std::get
    if (std::holds_alternative<int>(var0)) {
        std::cout << "var0 is an int: " << std::get<int>(var0) << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "var0 is a string: " << std::get<std::string>(var0) << std::endl;
    }

    if (std::holds_alternative<int>(var1)) {
        std::cout << "var1 is an int: " << std::get<int>(var1) << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "var1 is a string: " << std::get<std::string>(var1) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


Correct answer. But all it does is make the code 10x more complicated than it needs to be.

Instead of using std::holds_alternative and std::get, consider using std::visit instead.

@selbie true, should have asked for the use-case. c++ is already complex. why make it more

@RemyLebeau Ah but it seems like std::visit has a specify use case
